# One project two google analytics ids

Tags: google-analytics

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689560/two-google-analytics-id-on-one-website)
question I want to ask one more clarification:

I have a project. An application that I host on two different machines with two different domains for two different clients.

I have two applications registered in the Google Analytics portal.

Can I add the both tags as explained in the linked question and will I get data for the different application depending on which server I have hosted the app or, no matter the client, if I log into the first system, i will be registered on the second as well?

I am asking as the project is already build and packaged when I do the differentiation which goes to which server and am looking for quicker solution.

Answer (score 0):

A quicker solution would be using one GA property for tracking all your applications and having a user-level custom dimension there indicating which application it is.

An alternative, would be using N properties each for its own application and then use a rollup property: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6096167?hl=en

Your case doesn't sound like a case justifying using two properties at the same time on each of the apps. Please elaborate your case better if you still believe you have to use double tracking. Double tracking is a brutish solution and there are almost always more elegant solutions.